# Solutions for time-dependent sphere differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Suppose I have three suitably-smooth real-valued function $x(t), y(t), z(t)$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Let's consider the following differential equation:

$$\left( \frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial y(t)}{\partial t} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial z(t)}{\partial t} \right)^2 = C$$

where $C$ is real-valued constant.

Clearly this isn't the heat equation, wave equation, or Laplace's equation. The first difficulty *prima facie* is the non-linearity. Taking $u := \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$, $v := \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$, and $w := \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ we have the algebraic expression:

$$u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = C.$$

Taking the first derivative wrt $t$, we obtain:

$$2u \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + 2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + 2w\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} = 0$$

via the chain rule. Dividing both sides by 2, we obtain

$$u \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + w\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} = 0$$

But now looking at this I am not sure how to proceed. I considered Laplace transforming the expression, but that seems to lead to an integral I don't know how to solve.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Can you see it is the norm of a velocity vector? The solution is just the trajectory of a curve from a sphere with radius $\sqrt{C}$.

Comment: @MrProof I see the square velocity norm here, and supposing constant kinetic energy we could also suggest $C = \frac{2}{m} \text{KE}$ from a physics point of view. The question is originally motivated by physics. I am not assuming constant acceleration, so I cannot jump back to the kinematic equations here.

Comment: Is there any more information about the functions? Like initial values? Or the space they belong to?

Comment: @MrProof No, no more information about the functions, initial values, or the space. Sadly,  there may not be a general solution.

Comment: Transform it to spherical coordinates.

Comment: This is the [Eikonal equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation).